# Arrow keys on JavaScript game not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move the santa gif to the left. So far I have only put in the code for the left arrow but I cannot get it to move. I have my arrow icons in a div set to a z-index of 30 (higher than everything else on the page) so it shouldn't be that. Any help is much appreciated!!!!

[Here](http://udel.edu/~muldoon/finalproject/) is the link to what the game looks like so far, and [here](http://udel.edu/~muldoon/finalproject/index.css) is my external style sheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Santa Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script>
        var top = 350
        var left = 1250
        function move(rightorleft)
        {
            if(rightorleft == 'left')
            {
                document.getElementById("santa").style.position="absolute"
                left = left - 10
                document.getElementById("santa").style.left=left+"px"
            }
            else if(rightorleft == 'right')
            {
                document.getElementById("santa").style.position="absolute"
                left = left + 10
                document.getElementById("santa").style.left=left+"px"
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr id="top">
            <td>
                <p id="p1">Help Santa avoid storms and the eyes of curious children to deliver all the presents on time!</h1>
                <p id="p2">Santa score: 0</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="middle">
                <img class="clouds1" id="cloud1" src="cloud.png" width="200px">
                <img class="clouds1" id="cloud2" src="cloud.png" width="200px">
                <img class="clouds1" id="cloud3" src="cloud.png" width="200px">
                <img class="clouds1" id="cloud4" src="cloud.png" width="200px">
                <img class="clouds1" id="cloud5" src="cloud.png" width="200px">
                <img class="storms" id="storm1" src="storm.png" width="150px">
                <img class="storms" id="storm2" src="storm.png" width="150px">
                <img class="storms" id="storm3" src="storm.png" width="150px">
                <img class="storms" id="storm4" src="storm.png" width="150px">
                <img class="clouds2" id="cloud7" src="cloud.png" width="150px">
                <img class="clouds2" id="cloud8" src="cloud.png" width="150px">
                <img class="clouds2" id="cloud9" src="cloud.png" width="150px">
                <img class="clouds2" id="cloud10" src="cloud.png" width="150px">
                <img class="clouds2" id="cloud11" src="cloud.png" width="150px">
                <img class="clouds2" id="cloud12" src="cloud.png" width="150px">
                <img class="clouds2" id="cloud6" src="cloud.png" width="150px">
                <img id="santa" src="santa.gif" width="250px">
                <img id="hill" src="hill.png" width="785px" height="100px">
                <div id="kids"><img class="kids" id="kid1" src="kid1.png" width="100px">
                <img class="kids" id="kid2" src="kid2.png" width="100px">
                <img class="kids" id="kid3" src="kid3.png" width="100px">
                <img class="kids" id="kid4" src="kid4.png" width="100px">
                <img class="kids" id="kid5" src="kid5.png" width="100px"></div>
                <div id="houses"><img class="houses" id="house1" src="house.gif" width="150px">
                <img class="houses" id="house2" src="house.gif" width="150px">
                <img class="houses" id="house3" src="house.gif" width="150px">
                <img class="houses" id="house4" src="house.gif" width="150px">
                <img class="houses" id="house5" src="house.gif" width="150px"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="bottom">
                <div id="arrows">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="up.png" width="30px"><br>
                    <img src="left.png" width="30px" onClick="move('left')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <img src="right.png" width="30px"><br>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="down.png" width="30px">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button">Start (Easy)</button>
                    <button type="button">Start (Hard)</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>           
</body>
```

Comment: Where is your `key` event listener?

Comment: `<img src="right.png" width="30px">` nothing happens on `onclick`.Set `onclick()` event.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You have to add a `key` event, like as follows:</s>

```
body.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    if (key == 39) { //If pressed key is left
       move('left');
    }
    if (key == 37) { //If pressed key is right
       move('right');
    }
});
```

## Update

It's not problem in your JS actually it's problem in your CSS, in your CSS `#houses` & `#kids` overlaying your buttons which making them not working.

Use the following CSS:

```
#middle{ background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
table{ margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
#p1{ font-size: 105%;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
#p2{ font-family: Helvetica;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
td{ width: 770px;
    border: 2px solid #003399;
}
#bottom{ font-size: 150%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #80aaff;
    padding: 5px;
}
#top{ background-color: #80aaff;
    line-height: 85%;
}
.clouds1{ position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    float: left;
}
#cloud2{ position: relative;
    left: 137.5px;
}
#cloud3{ position: relative;
    left: 82.5px;
}
#cloud4{ position: relative;
    left: 37.5px;
}
#cloud5{ position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: -131px;
}
.storms{ padding: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 170px;
}
#storm4{ position: relative;
    left: 130px;
    bottom: 362px;
}
.clouds2{ position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    float: left;
    bottom: 325.5px;
}
#cloud6{ position: relative;
    bottom: 519.5px;
    left: 180px;
}
#cloud7{ position: relative;
}
#cloud8{ position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
#cloud9{ position: relative;
    right: 90px;
}
#cloud10{ position: relative;
    bottom: 519.5px;
    left: 320px;
}
#cloud11{ position: relative;
    bottom: 519.5px;
    left: 270px;
}
#cloud12{ position: relative;
    bottom: 519.5px;
    left: 220px;
}
#hill{ position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
}
#kids{
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 20px;
    bottom: 49px;
    position: absolute;
}
.kids{
    padding: 22px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
}
#houses{
    z-index: 20;
    bottom: 68px;
    position: absolute;
}
.houses{
    position: relative;
}
#arrows{ float: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
    z-index: 30;
}
button{ font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    color: #003399;
    border: 2px solid #003399;
}
#santa{ position: absolute;
    left: 1250px;
    top: 350px;
    z-index: 30;
}
```

Comment: I see how this should fix the problem but it is still not working for me. I tried it in firefox, chrome, and safari

Answer (score 0):

hello there was some css issue in your code which is i solved.

You can check on following link.

```
"https://jsfiddle.net/spankajd/tbjxba99/"
```

Comment: I see how this should fix the problem and it works on the site you just included but it still does not work for me. I tried it in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari

Comment: still the same, the arrows are not making the sleigh move

Comment: @SarahMarie : What all you need to do is apply css properly.. that's it your JavaScript code works fine... so please apply css accordingly .. :)

Comment: I did and its still not working. I even tried giving my table and background image a largely negative z-index

Comment: Ok I did, I am not sure what needs to be changed to console.log or anything else that jsfeddle might be different about. I actually restarted and kept everything naturally on the right side of the screen and put my images in lists and didn't mix position: relative and absolute this time. Now everything is positioned absolutely and none of the paths of my images should be in the way of the arrows. I finished making the rest of the game as well